# Does Dota 2 have needs to level summoner as in League of Legends?

Tags: dota-2

In League of Legends players need to level up their summoner to level 30.

As summoner level increases, players will unlock summoner spells, runes, and masteries. Is there a similar system in DOTA 2? And if so, how does it work?

Is there something that you need to grind to unlock it in DOTA 2?

Comment: Besides some game modes (progressively but quite fast), ranked matchmaking (level 13) and rarity of random drops to prevent farming  (you are eligible for arcana - the rarest category - at level 7 I think), leveling up only gives you a guaranteed item drop.

Comment: There's a lot of basic questions you're asking here.  I'd recommend doing some research on your own before asking here.

Comment: @Frank all my questions are made after searching question in other resources. Also as much I search as many question arises. Some answers I found myself but some needs to be asked. And I am not aware of any restrictions about the number of questions asked at stackexchange sites.

Comment: There is no restriction; we won't stop you from asking more.  What *can* happen, though, is a lot of downvotes.  We don't mind helping, but we do expect you to attempt to help yourself, first.

Comment: @Frank I agree with you that user must search first and only after ask question here. I did research on every question before asking here. But I dont understand why to down vote only because "there is to much questions". Also I understand that for experienced users it becoming difficult to understand why newcomer is asking too mach basic questions. Downvoting only because to much questions harms the idea of sharing knowledge. I also understand you particularly may not downvoting my questions but are giving me information why others may downvote my questions. Anyway thank you for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A level 1 'player' in Dota2 has no locks or restrictions on in-game heroes, abilities, items, or anything else that affects gameplay. A professional player could use a brand new account with no meaningful effect on performance.

Low-level accounts are unable to play some of the more advanced modes, mostly in an attempt to counteract smurfing. These modes will be unlocked reasonably quickly as you play.

Comment: I don't think game modes restrictions counter smurfing as All Pick is available from the very beginning

Comment: @T_O Aware, but Captain's games and Ranked are limited for a while, which is where most boosting/smurfing would otherwise occur.